# Recommended way to execute long running queries

Tags: java, jooq

What is the recommended way to execute long-running queries in jOOQ?

Are there any downsides in executing query asynchronously(except blocking operation on `ForkJoinPool` which could be mitigated by supplying execution to dedicated thread pool), converting result into `CompletableFuture` and calling `get()` method with specified timeout?

```
dslFactory
    .create()
    .selectFrom(TABLE_NAME)
    .where(conditions)
    .fetchAsync()
    .toCompletableFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, when running jOOQ queries on top of JDBC (sync or async, doesn't matter), you're going to block somewhere, and you have to manage those resources somehow. In a lot of cases, this isn't a big problem.

If blocking turns out to be a problem, jOOQ 3.15 starts supporting R2DBC which allows for running your query reactively, without blocking in the client: https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/15/reactive-sql-with-jooq-3-15-and-r2dbc

Your query would then look like this:

```java
Flux<TableNameRecord> result = Flux.from(
    dslFactory
        .create()
        .selectFrom(TABLE_NAME)
        .where(conditions));
```